# How to set a range equal to visible cells in two columns which are not next to each other

Tags: excel, vba, range, visible

I have columns A through J which are filtered, so some rows are hidden. Row 1 is always a header row and I do not want this.
I want a range object for visible cells in columns E and J only. Note that there will be hidden rows in between the visible rows.

Thanks
Andrew.

Comment: **1)** What have you tried? Hard to help without seeing a code base. **2)** `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and `Union` function will help I think.

Comment: I tried Union and it did not work. It only returns the range up to the first hidden row. Set RegionRange = .Range("E2: J" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) then: Set RegionRange = Application.Union(RegionRange.Columns("A:A"), RegionRange.Columns("F:F"))

Comment: edit your original question with the code you tried, don't place it in comments

Comment: (Please add the code to your original post, and format with code tags `{}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. I made some obvious assumptions you'll have to modify.

```
With worksheets("mySheet")

     Dim lastRow as Long
     lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).Row

     Dim filterRange as Range
     Set filterRange = .Range("A1:J" & lastRow)

     With filterRange

         .AutoFilter 1, "myFilter"

         Set region1Range as Range
         Set region1Range = .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

         Set region2Range as Range
         Set region2Range = .Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    End With

End With

Dim regionRange
Set regionRange = Union(region1Range, region2Range)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I just came to a separate similar conclusion, but your code is more readable: `Set testrange = Application.Union(.Range("E2: E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), .Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`